# Is this apple or some other fruit?

Tags: identification, fruits

[image]

What fruit is this? It looks like apple in its early stage. It even tastes and smells like apple (but sour). It was hanging in bunches in the tree.

**EDIT:** From the comments, I have concluded its [crab apple](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=crab%20apple&qs=IM&form=QBILPG&sp=1&pq=crab%20app&sc=8-8&sk=&cvid=9AC31E4A99134E548078BD2363E61CD1).

Comment: I believe that to be a crab apple.

Comment: Possibly what are known as Transcendent Crabapple http://www.specialtyproduce.com/produce/Transcendent_Crabapples_11043.php.  Cut a fruit open across its equator to see if it has a core like an apple, that would confirm  its a crabapple

Comment: @Bamboo: When I cut it, the core looks exactly like a normal apple but scaled to its size.

Comment: crabapple then... not usually eaten raw, sometimes used to make  jams or jellies,or just grown for  decorative, aesthetic purposes - and the birds

Comment: Crab apple trees are sometimes used as pollinators for nearby apple trees though you should use one with the same colour flowers as the one you want to pollinate.

Comment: @GrahamChiu: that's not true, a crabapple does not have to have the same colour flowers as an apple at all - it just needs to flower at the same time  as whatever Apple tree you're trying to grow.

Comment: @bamboo Research conducted in the United States and at Orange in NSW has shown that bees, when out foraging apple blossoms, tend to stay with the same colour flower and fly past a different colour, especially if the blossom colours are very different, such as deep red or white with a tinge of pink. This could negate cross-pollination. https://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/agriculture/horticulture/pomes/apples/crabapple-pollinators

Comment: Whilst that link makes interesting reading, I would just point out its aimed at  agriculture, not horticulture, so for large, commercial orchards rather than small fruiting areas, and reference is made to the lack of bumblebees in Australia, meaning choosing a crabapple by flower colour maybe  of more importance there.  America has no shortage of bumblebees, like most other countries, and bumblebees have no trouble switching between colours.

Comment: "Of the estimated 20 000 species of bees found around the world (Michener, 2007), only a small proportion are known apple pollinators. The bee species involved in apple pollination differ among apple-growing regions, and within regions of the countries that grow apples. The exception is perhaps the honey bee, Apis mellifera, which is the most important, managed pollinator in the world. " FAO, A MANUAL ON 
APPLE POLLINATION